# What does this line return?

Tags: java

```
int lf = ((t.left==null) = (t.right==null)) ? 1:0;
```

it returns 1 if the statement in the bigger parenthesis is true, but in the middle, whats the point of assigning  right value to lefT?

Comment: Does that even compile? The compiler shouldn't allow assignments to expressions.

Comment: There is no inner assignmnet, otherwise the code wouldn't compile. THe third operator must be another `==`.

Comment: ((t.left == null) **==** (t.right == null)) : 1 is returned if *t.left AND t.right* are both 'null' or 'not null' . If only one is 'null' zero is returned. ((Object)o == null) return a boolean. If you return zero and one you can use true or false and replace *int lf* by *boolean lf*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Normally you'd have an equal sign to assign. The return of the assigned is the same as the RHS of the expression.

You'd use an equal sign in a expression within an if to assign and check the result at the same time.

```
// return first and third items added if they exist.
if ((list = GetItems()).Length > 2) { return list[0] + list[2]; }
```

Right here all you have is a compiler error because `t.left==null` evaluates to `(true/false)` and you can't assign to that.

Comment: A little warning on this syntax trick, it can get very confusing if overused. `if (((area = length * width) > 100) && (area < 1000) && ((area2 = length2 * width2) > 1000) && ((totalarea = area + area2) < (absolutemaxarea = (area4 = area5 + area6) - bufferarea))) { return absolutemaxarea - totalarea + bufferarea; } // what just happened`

Comment: just to add, the line above was to determine, in a binary search tree that how many nodes has only ONE child using recursion.. not sure if that helps

Comment: @warpstar If you want to know that, then the line would be `((t.left==null) != (t.right==null)) ? 1 : 0;` This would return true IFF only one of the nodes has a child, false if both or neither have a child.

Answer (score 1):

If both `t.left` and `t.right` are either `null` or not `null` **at the same time**, then `lf` is `1` otherwise it is `0`.

Also you have a typo in there. The line should be

```
int lf = ((t.left==null) == (t.right==null)) ? 1:0;
```

Notice the `==` between the two null checks.

Comment: I don't think this is true, I think whatever the left thing evaluates, it will be replaced with the right thing. I think only the right thing is what matters. edit: there is no == between the two null checks

Comment: @ajax333221 sorry i didn't notice his typo... in java it would not compile if there was only one `=` (assignment)

Comment: Also, how are you sure that's the intended compare? What if the coder wanted `((t.left == null) != (t.right == null))`. Never assume. Always go find out what was intended if at all possible.